# CodeIgniter - container view to get list of scripts (js) needed by sub-views from those subs

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, view, containers, subview

I have a controller that opens a container view. The container then hands the building of the page to several views including the "html_meta" view and the "top_bar", "side_bar", "content" views. However, the content contains several different views too many of which can be considered gadgets, or small contained html divs with different data, script actions.

Question: 
If I want the HTML header/meta to include only the scripts that that the specific gadget views need, is there a way for the gadget views to send the necessary script components back up the line to the container view so that it can process them and add the scripts to the html head?

- If it helps I can include the code, but for now, I think it gets messy here.  However, if you need code to visualize it, no problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example my controller calls the main `container` but I have to pass it my content which is from another view as such

```
...
$content['content'] = $this->load->view('about/index', $data, true);
...
$this->load->view('layout/container', $content');
```

Then `layout/container.php` contains several

```
...
$this->load->view("layout/html_meta");
...
$this->load->view("layout/top_bar");
...
<div id="content">
  <?php echo $content?>
</div>
```

It's possible but it's not the subviews "informing" the "html_meta" to include the javascripts that it needs because your views are rendered from the main container down to the sub views.

What you can do is create a helper for your external java scripts. I'm thinking of having a javascript group for each of your widgets such as

```
function getJSforWidgetOne() {
   $scripts = array();
   $scripts[] = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js";
   $scripts[] = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.js";
   return $scripts;
}
```

Then in your controller function you also pass those scripts, or possible your constructor.

```
$content['custom_js'] = getJSForWidgetOne();
$content['content'] = $this->load->view('about/index', $data, true);
...
$this->load->view('layout/container', $content');
```

So now, `$custom_js` is accessible in your `layout/container.php`. But it's not yet in `layout/html_meta`. So I'll assign this to an array, and pass it again to `layout/html_meta`.

```
...
$for_html_meta['custom_js'] = $custom_js;
$this->load->view("layout/html_meta", $for_html_meta);
...
$this->load->view("layout/top_bar");
...
<div id="content">
  <?php echo $content?>
</div>
```

Then in your `layout/html_meta`, you can now use `$custom_js` to insert additional javascripts aside from your common scripts.

Comment: Right. Got it. Thanks @ace. The controller runs things and is boss. But sometimes, the boss takes advice from the worker bees. I'd like to be able for some feedback mechanism from the view to the controller. For example, depending on what the view spits out, sometimes I want to include a js file, but sometimes a different js file. The  output would then have slightly different user functionality. But, the js link I'd prefer to have either in the html header or as the last part of the body element. So, the view wouldn't be inserting the script tag, the controller would.

Comment: Perhaps I'm asking too much of the MVC model where the logic of page building is almost entirely in the controller. However, the view still has to decide when to display certain things, and when not to. Yes, the data for that decision is passed from the controller and is accessible there, so it's not an impossible task to have the controller take care of it. As the same time, with nested views, the each controller will have to make these decisions, whereas the single view could otherwise.

Comment: I understand the need of having organized js links in the `<head>` or at the last part of the `<body>`. But with the way CodeIgniter works, you'll need to have the js links nested in an if-else or switch-case implementation in the header view or the footer view.